# where the icons are saved in template?

Tags: html, css

Hello first of all thanks for giving time to my question,
I've a template here:
http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/58725.html

On the top left side there is a icon of home, i've copied full website but icons is missing in my file, even I've copied full images, css and js files.
When I inspect element i see the span with class:

```
<span class="icon fl-continuous-house150"></span>
```

I know this class is handling icon but can't figure out why it's not showing icon in my copy even css is there. please tell me if I'm missing something.

Comment: A CSS class for an icon indicates an icon _font_ is being used (quicker, better, more flexible than images). Did the template include fonts, and are they loading correctly?

Comment: How did you 'copy' the full website? Did you copy paste the sources and then saved the assets manually from the hosted version?

Comment: Ensure that you placed all your folders as specified in the code

Comment: yes just pasted source codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have CSS file like this:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("../icons/Flaticon.eot");
    src: url("../icons/Flaticon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("../icons/Flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
        url("../icons/Flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("../icons/Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

//how to display icons on website like fa fa-...

```
.fa
{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Flaticon;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

//names of implemented icons

```
.fa-clock:before { content: "\f100"; }
.fa-cross:before { content: "\f101"; }
.fa-facebook:before { content: "\f102"; }
.fa-google-plus:before { content: "\f103"; }
.fa-hamburger:before { content: "\f104"; }
.fa-left-arrow:before { content: "\f105"; }
.fa-linked-in:before { content: "\f106"; }
.fa-location:before { content: "\f107"; }
.fa-phone:before { content: "\f108"; }
.fa-right-arrow:before { content: "\f109"; }
.fa-star:before { content: "\f10a"; }
.fa-twitter:before { content: "\f10b"; }
.fa-up-arrow:before { content: "\f10c"; }
```

1. If you don't have files .woff , .eot, .svg, .ttf i reccomand to write an email to [TemplateMonster](http://www.templatemonster.com/customer-complaints.php) or just download some free icons

I really reccomand you to go to the [flaticon.com](http://www.flaticon.com/), choose some free icons and download "Icon Font" (very important). They have multiple of them and you should just write in footer or something, that icons was made by ... from [flaticon.com](http://www.flaticon.com/) ;)

Hope i helped

Comment: Thanks, just found, and downloaded those font files :) it's working now :)